# Java - How to do Gzip compression of java object

Tags: java, json, compression, gzip

How to compress a Java pojo object using Gzip?

Below code compress a string -

```
public static String compress(String str, String inEncoding) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            return str;
        }
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
            gzip.write(str.getBytes(inEncoding));
            gzip.close();
            return URLEncoder.encode(out.toString("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Instead of String str as a parameter, how to use below pojo class object (Client cc) and compress?

Pojo class -

```
Class client {
Public string name;
Public string location;
//Getter and setter methods
}
```

How can i compress and decompress this client pojo class using gzip.?

Comment: You tagged **`json`**, so why don't you convert the POJO to JSON, which is a string value, so you can then compress that with your existing code?

Comment: *FYI:* Do not decode the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a `String`. Instead, encode the bytes using **Base64 encoding**.

Comment: The pojo will have large volume data, nearly 1GB. So converting pojo to jaon string might be problematic in terms of memory consumsion.

Comment: Then why did you tag your question `json`? Remove the tag if you *know* you don't want JSON. --- Anyway, that's a non-issue if you use a streaming JSON generator, and compress the text output directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compress your Client class which implements serializable using gzip by doing the following :

```
public static bytes[] compressThis(Client client){
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(client);
  ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOut);
  objectOut.writeObject(client);
  objectOut.close();
  return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Following which you can decompress it by doing the following :

```
public static getClientFrom(bytes[] bytes){
  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
  GZIPInputStream gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
  ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(gzipIn);
  Client client = (Client) objectIn.readObject();
  objectIn.close();
  return client;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This compresses using default compression i guess. Is it possible to specify something lik utf-8 or utf-16 for encoding in Gzip? How to check the size of client class object before and after compression?

Comment: Size? count the `bytes.length`

Comment: Gzip is an algorithm for compressing and not encoding. Encoding by definition is changing the format (eg: nary, hex, decimal, base64, DER, BER) which aren't (usually) meant to change the data's meaning. Size expansion / reduction may of course be a result of a different encoding.